# Complex DB tables problem

Tags: mysql, database

I am developing a student results website in which :-

1. Every year has its own subjects ( 1st year has sub1 , sub2 , sub3 and 2nd year other subjects and so on ) which will be added , deleted by the admin of the site .

I designed three tables :-

1. "Students" : contains info about students and their current year .
2. "Subjects" : info about subjects .
3. "Years" : info about years in the school .
4. "Years_Subjects" : relation between the years and its subjects .

The problem now is **How can i store a result ??** how can i design the results table to contain degrees for different subjects ???

Thanks

Comment: Erm, `Student_Subject_results (student_id,subject_id,score)`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: -1 for the title. This is not complex, it's trivial.

Comment: @moritz - it's trivial maybe for you. And maybe for 3m its complex enough to post on SO.

Comment: Perhaps you could post the table definitions you have so far. Then we'll be able to offer better advice.

Comment: @Preet Sangha - i was commenting on the title, not on the question or on the place where it is posted.

Answer (score 0):

Results will be a table that has the following values (results) and the following foreign keys
Student, Subject, (possibly year)

Have a degrees table and an association table between subject and degree

```
Results  -> Student
         -> Subject
         -> Year?

Degree  <- DegreeSubject -> Subject
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a Results table like this.

```
Results
--------
Student_ID (FK to Students)
Years_Subjects_ID (FK to Years_Subjects)
Score
```

I don't think it would be best to have a FK to Years and another FK to Subjects, because you won't be able to easily prevent a row that represents a subject that was not offered in a particular year.